# Get Child Element being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

OK, so here's my issue (it must be simple, but I still cannot figure this one out)...

**I've got a sample HTML code like the one below :**

```
<!-- New Website #1 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style='min-height:0px;'>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dev.css" />


    </head>

    <body id="jqm-website-6926" class=""  >


        <!-- New Page #1 -->
        <div data-role="page" comp-id="jqm-page-6271" id="jqm-page-6271" class="" data-add-back-btn="false" data-back-btn-text="" data-back-btn-theme="" data-dom-cache="false" data-theme="" data-title="" >

            <!-- New Header #1 -->
            <div data-role="header" comp-id="jqm-header-364" id="jqm-header-364" class="" data-position="" data-fullscreen="false" data-theme="" >
                <h1></h1>
            </div>
            <!-- / New Header #1 -->

            <!-- New Content #1 -->
            <div data-role="content" comp-id="jqm-content-3537" id="jqm-content-3537" class="" data-theme=""  >

                <!-- New Button #1 -->
                <div comp-id="jqm-button-1547" >
                    <a data-role="button" id="jqm-button-1547" class="" data-corners="true" data-icon="" data-iconpos="left" data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="false" data-mini="false" data-shadow="true" data-theme=""  href="#" data-transition="(null)">

                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- / New Button #1 -->
            </div>
            <!-- / New Content #1 -->
        </div>
        <!-- / New Page #1 -->

        <!-- New Page #1 -->
        <div data-role="page" comp-id="jqm-page-9207" id="jqm-page-9207" class="" data-add-back-btn="false" data-back-btn-text="" data-back-btn-theme="" data-dom-cache="false" data-theme="" data-title="" >

        </div>
        <!-- / New Page #1 -->


        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
        <script src="custom.js"></script>
        <script src="dev.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- / New Website #1 -->
```

All I want to do is when a specific element, with the `comp-id` attribute set, is clicked - we highlight (by adding the `msp-selected` class) *just* that specific element.

However, this is not working...

**This is what I've tried :**

```
function removeAll()
{
    $("[comp-id]").each(function() {
        if ($(this)!==undefined) {
            $(this).removeClass("msp-selected");
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('[comp-id]:not(.msp-selected)').on('click', function(e) {
        removeAll();

        $(this).addClass('msp-selected');
    });
});
```

**However, here's the problem :**

- When clicking on the button (`comp-id="jqm-button-1547"`)
- It highlights : a) first the button, b) then `jqm-content-3537`, c) then `jqm-page-6271`
- In a few words, in the end, the 'page' is highlighted, instead of the button.

Any ideas?

---

**And here's a fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/CTZD3/

Comment: didn't you ask this question before as well ? ;) just asking because i think you weren't clear enough in that question

Comment: @AdityaSaxena Well, I did. I'm just reposting, because I think I now know how to properly... phrase it, and what the really issue was... ;-)

Comment: cool...I was just checking what happened to the responses on that one

Comment: Have you tried marking the event as handled?

Comment: `if ($(this)!==undefined) {` this is a heavenly truthy condition.

Comment: @TylerDurden I'm (obviously) not such a guru with javascript/jquery (it just happened that some part of a huge project of mine depends on that...)... so, would you mind elaborating on that a bit?

Comment: try event.stopPropogation() or event.preventDefault() then you can test event.isDefaultPrevented() or event.IsPropogationStopped() before adding the class msp-selected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can stop the event to be propagated to parents elements with [`event.stopPropagation();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('[comp-id]:not(.msp-selected)').on('click', function(e) {
        removeAll();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).addClass('msp-selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: Whoa! Was it *that* simple?! You're close to becoming my hero - I think (though I still cannot believe it does) work! :-) Thanks A LOT, buddy!

Comment: Well, you're welcome ;) Don't forget to check the answer as answering your question ;)

Comment: Well... I'm not... It's just the compulsory SO delay time... Thanks again! ;-)